# Create User Dashboard as startpage

Tags: views, organic-groups

hope that you can help me.

Version: Drupal 6/7

i need information about a user dashboard.

we want to create a intranet solution with bug/ticket reporting/scrum functionality and need for a overview a User/Team overview (newest issues/newest tasks etc.). but i don't found any help/information about a user/team dashboard.

1.) can i set a dashboard as startpage?

Greets Frank

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Homebox](http://drupal.org/project/homebox) and redirect the user to their individual dashboard on login (possibly using [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) or [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules)).  I've used it before and it's pretty neat.

Following that, you just create views to display your tickets/issues/tasks etc and display them in the homebox.